# Welding machine schematic: PWM controller connections

Tags: circuit-analysis, pwm, dc-dc-converter, schematic

[image: control board of Aiken 200 welding machine]

I don't understand why the VFB pin of the [UC3845AD](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3845a.pdf) PWM controller is grounded, and why the compensator pin is connected to the output of the LM224 through VD1 and VD2.

Comment: Why not take a look at the functional block diagram in the data sheet. It should all become clear when you do this professor.

Comment: Grounding the FB disables the internal op-amp by making it rail up to 5 V with a 1-mA maximum current capability. It is then safe and easy to externally pull the COMP pin down via either an optocoupler or an external circuit such as the one involving the LM324.